# Why do I can not call the static method in Spring service?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I write a service call serviceA like these:

```
@Service
public class serviceAImpl  implements AService { 
@Override
public String getRedisCluster(Para para) {
    return AreaManager.getInstance().getRedisClusterCodeByArea(para.getArea());
}
}
```

AreaManager is a Singleton pattern class without @service,the code like these:

```
public class AreaManager {  
private static final AreaManager INSTANCE = new AreaManager(); 
private SysDictConfigDao sysDictConfigDao;
public static AreaManager getInstance() {
    return INSTANCE;
}
private AreaManager() {
    sysDictConfigDao = (SysDictConfigDao) ServiceLocator.lookup("sysDictConfigDao"); 
    //do some business
} 
}
```

Now in the other service called serviceB to call getRedisCluster method,but something is wrong.I use @Service and @PostConstruct to the AreaManager class can fix it,but I don't know why the static singleton pattern can not be used?

```
@Service
public class serviceBImpl  implements BService { 
@Autowired
private AService aService;
...
//NoClassDefFoundError could not initialize class AreaManager
String redisClusterCode = aService.getRedisCluster(data);
}
```

Comment: Spring doesn't instantiate any classes during startup. It just create proxies. It does it ONLY for the annotated Spring components. That's why you can't get the instance of the singleton in this phase.